# Loop over comma-separated substrings without also breaking on spaces

Tags: shell

I have a variable like with comma separated values and need to loop and i am using below code

```
Var=test_v1,"Log Processor",test_v2
for i in ${Var//,/ }
do
    echo "Variables are  "${i}" assined"
done
```

**Outputs:**

```
Variables are test_v1 assined
Variables are Log assined
Variables are Processor assined
```

Its not taking whole word having double quotes as single and output it gives me like  Log and Processor are different but its single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either (better) use `read -a` to read into an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ arrays are a bash feature, not guaranteed in /bin/sh
Var=test_v1,"Log Processor",test_v2
IFS=, read -a Array <<<"$Var"          # this updates IFS only for the duration of 'read'
for i in "${Array[@]}"; do             # now loop over elements in the array read created
    echo "Variables are ${i} assined"
done
```

Or (worse) change `IFS` to contain only characters you want to use to split fields and disable globbing, so you can use an unquoted expansion safely:

```
Var=test_v1,"Log Processor",test_v2
IFS=,              # set the comma as the only field separator
set -f             # disable globbing
for i in $Var; do  # perform an unquoted expansion to split on IFS
    echo "Variables are ${i} assined"
done
# WARNING: This code left globbing disabled and ',' as the only field separator!
```

---

Because `${Var//,/ }` changes commas to spaces, in the result, all spaces and commas are indistinguishable, so you split on both. Don't do that; instead, read into an array and iterate over its contents.